# Remove all text between 2 headers Word 2010, using VBA

Tags: vba, text, replace, ms-word

I have 2 headers or markers that are a part of my RTF document.  In my example I am showing a sentence when in reality it will be multiple sentences or paragraphs.  I have used brackets instead of less than and greater than signs as they disappear in my question.  All I want to do is replace the text between the 2 markers with the following sentence, "text goes here", without quotation marks.

[EmbeddedReport]Lots of text, thousands of character, multiple paragraphs[/EmbeddedReport]

I want replace all the text between the 2 markers replaced with "text goes here".

It would end up looking like this...

```
"[EmbeddedReport]text goes here[/EmbeddedReport]"
```

I've literally spent 2 days trying to solve this.  Any help would be appreciated.

---

This is the last thing I tried...

```
Sub RemoveReport()

    Dim c As Range
    Dim StartWord As String, EndWord As String

    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory



    StartWord = "<ImageTable>"
    EndWord = "</ImageTable>"

    Set c = ActiveDocument.Content
    c.Find.ClearFormatting
    c.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With c.Find
        .Text = StartWord & "*" & EndWord
       ' MsgBox (.Text)
        .Replacement.Text = "<ImageTable>text goes here</ImageTable>"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With

    c.Find.Execute

    While c.Find.Found
        Debug.Print c.Text
        '~~> I am assuming that the start word and the end word will only
        '~~> be in the start and end respectively and not in the middle
        Debug.Print Replace(Replace(c.Text, StartWord, ""), EndWord, "")
        c.Find.Execute
    Wend



End Sub
```

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it. Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. **My solution** would be to use the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839118.aspx) object with [MatchWildcards](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838695.aspx) property set to `True`.  Give it a shot, and if you can't figure it out, we can help.

Comment: @David Zemens...I'm new to StackOverFlow.com.  Sorry for the inconvenience.  I have edited and added the code.  It just doesn't do anything.  I did borrow the code from similar problems I found on-line.  This isn't the only they I tried but was unsuccessful with other things I tried as well.  This bit of code looks the most logical to me but I'm certainly missing something.

Comment: This code is very similar to what I suggest. Give me a minute I will tweak it.

Comment: OK, my answer was not as good as I thought but hopeuflly it helps. I could not figure out how to get it to find angle brackets, so my solution is for square brackets.  Anyways, it should point you in the right direction at least; I hope it helps :)

Comment: How many documents do you need to do this to?

Answer (score 2):

Word VBA is not my area of expertise, but it seems similar to a question I answered a few days ago.

Turns out the wildcard match was not doing what I hoped it would do, or at least it was not reliable. Also, I ran in to some trouble using angle brackets, so this uses square brackets.  I suspect that word treats the angle brackets as markup/syntax, and thus does not interpret them as text in the Find object.  There is probably a way around this, but Word VBA is not my specialty.  There is also probably a more elegant solution, but again, Word VBA is not my specialty :)

Try something like this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()
Dim doc As Document
Dim txtRange As Range
Dim startTag As String
Dim endTag As String
Dim s As Long
Dim e As Long

startTag = "[EmbeddedReport]"
endTag = "[/EmbeddedReport]"
Set doc = ActiveDocument
Set txtRange = doc.Content
'Find the opening tag
With txtRange.Find
    .Text = startTag
    .Forward = True
    .Execute
    If .Found Then
        s = txtRange.Start
    Else
        GoTo EarlyExit
    End If
End With
'Find the closing tag
Set txtRange = doc.Range(txtRange.End, doc.Content.End)
With txtRange.Find
    .Text = endTag
    .Forward = True
    .Execute
    If .Found Then
        e = txtRange.End
    Else
        GoTo EarlyExit
    End If
End With
Set txtRange = doc.Range(s, e)
txtRange.Text = startTag & "text goes here" & endTag

Exit Sub


EarlyExit:
MsgBox "Header not found in this document!", vbInformation

End Sub
```

It takes some time to figure it out at first, but learning to navigate the [object model reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837519.aspx) documentation for VBA will make these tasks a lot easier to figure out in the future.

Comment: David Zemens...this looks very promising.  It appears to be working!  I need to do further testing.  I may comment later tonight or tomorrow after testing.  Thank you for heading me in the right direction.